# Passing arguments to Start-Job scriptblock?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'd like to setup a cmdlet to start and stop mysql, and I'm trying to do so with Start-Job. the I've got the following in my Powershell profile:

```
$mysqlpath = "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin"
Function Start-Mysql
{
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock { & "$mysqlpath\mysqld.exe" }
}
```

The variable doesn't seem to be expanding in the job command however? I must be missing some sort of scoping rule. Could someone please advise? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you have to use the `-argumentlist` parameter see [get-help start-job](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849698.aspx) :

```
 start-job  -ScriptBlock { & $args[0] } -ArgumentList @($mysqlpath )
```

note that in V3 you just have to use the prefix `using:` before your varname ex:

```
  Start-Job -ScriptBlock { & "$using:mysqlpath\mysqld.exe" }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I'm wondering if it's because I need to run the command with Admin privileges? As a test, I ran 
`start-job -ScriptBlock {& $arg[0]} -ArgumentList @("start cmd.exe")`, which also fails to launch cmd.exe. Powershell just reports the command as "& $arg[0]". Shouldn't that have expanded?

Comment: @Kayasax maybe is $args[0] ?? with 's' ;)

Comment: That was it. I think I need to go make another pot of coffee :P. Cheers.

Comment: @C.B. Don't be shy about editing an answer that has an obvious minor error like that.  :-)

Comment: @KeithHill It wasn't a shyness problem ;) just waiting for Kayasax fix it.... but in future I will do it!

Comment: Could it be that the double right accolade `{ & $args[0] }}` in the current first line of code in the answer, is a typo? It is asymmetric, and the command tested by @Drism only contains a single accolade, which is claimed to be working after adding an `s` between `arg` and `[0]` implying the single accolade, instead of the double, is fine.

Answer (score 2):

[Loïc MICHEL's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14664983/584676) is correct, but if you find it becomes difficult to deal with remembering which positional argument is which within the `ScriptBlock`, I'd like to offer a trick using the `param` keyword. Within the `ScriptBlock`, begin the body with `param` like you would for an advanced function, and put your code after also as if it were a function:

> **Note:** The `ScriptBlock` `param` name does not need to be the same in the `ScriptBlock` and current session, it can be the same or something totally different. The important thing is you match the correct argument positionally in the `-ArgumentList`.

```
Start-Job { param( $mysqlpath ) & "$mysqlpath\mysqld.exe" } -ArgumentList $mysqlpath
```

This works because a `ScriptBlock` is just an unnamed function, so you can define parameters in *mostly* the same way you can when defining a proper function. The arguments in `-ArgumentList` are passed to the `ScriptBlock` as positional arguments in the order provided, so by default the order the arguments are passed is the same order they will be bound to named parameters in.

While the `$using:` scope is syntactically easier to work with, this method gets you the best of all worlds here, as the `$using:` scope cannot be used within the current session. This is incredibly useful you have a `ScriptBlock` that needs to be able to execute in *any* context and it's complicated enough that referencing the arguments by index becomes difficult to manage. This approach allows you to name your parameters and works with any `ScriptBlock` in *all* execution contexts, whether it's `Start-Job`, `Invoke-Command`, `powershell.exe`, or executing a `ScriptBlock` with the call operator `&`.

This is one of (if not the) most portable solution if you want to use named variables instead of referencing `$args[i]` for every variable.